# How to scale a light's size , and strength proportionally with the rest of the scene in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, lighting

I have a question regarding the scaling of lights alongside the scaling of a scene in Blender.

Say I have a scene consisting of a plane acting as a surface, and a simple white UV Sphere. Both are at their default size

I have an Area lamp shining directly perpendicular to the top of the UV sphere. The Area Lamp is at a distance of 6 units on the Z-axis, while the UV is at 0 .

I want to scale the entire scene down by a sixth of its original size. I can scale both the plane and sphere by 1/6 to reduce them to a sixth of their size

However, when I do the same to the area light, and reduce its strength and size by sixth in the material editor, it simply does not light the scene the same way as prior to scaling

[image: This is how they look un-scaled]

[image: Mesh,plane scaled by sixth, light strength size scaled by sixth. Still does not look like first image at all]

So with that, comes my question. How do I scale everything in the scene , lights included , while also maintaining the same distance between mesh and lights, proportionally so that they look the exact same as before in the render,  with only the scale values affected?

As you can see in following images,first image  is how it  looks un-scaled. This is how the scene should LOOK

In the second image, Mesh,plane are scaled by a sixth, light strength size scaled by sixth. Still does not look like first image at all

Comment: Hello :). You need to scale the light strength according to the [inverse square law](https://byjus.com/inverse-square-law-calculator/). It's not linear.

Comment: @JachymMichal so if it follows the inverse square law, what values should I plug in into the area lamp , in my case to match the first picture?

Comment: Use the link, it's a calculator :). I'll post a full answer if I find the time.

Comment: @JachymMichal I don't see a calculator or link?

Comment: @brockmann I'm sorry, I don't get you. Ate you asking me to use the calculator app? If so, what values do I plug in?

Comment: @brockmann sorry, my bad. I got notified for some reason on mobile

Comment: @HankRyan click the link that says "inverse square law", and it will take you to the calculator he was talking about.

Comment: @EricXue I clicked it. I'm very confused as to what values to input there. Where does the strength value go? By what value do I divide it by? What does it have to do with radiation?

Comment: @HankRyan The inverse square law is a relationship between the intensity of a radiation (e.g. light), and the distance an observer is away from it. It looks like you want to be albe to increase the intensity of a light, but then move it so the lighting would be the same. Plug in the initial wattage into the first value (this should be fine). The value you would like to increase it to goes into the second value. The first distance goes into the third value, and finally, write the letter "x" into the last value. The calculator will solve for x. The new light should be X units away from the UV.

Comment: @EricXue My issue is that I do not know what value to increase or decrease my wattage to. And by distance, do you mean distance from the sphere or the size of the area lamp itself?

Comment: @HankRyan That is totally fine. Then set the final wattage as "x", and instead of "x" for the final distance, replace it with the desired distance. By distance, I mean distance from the object as that is what the calculator is designed to do for you.

Comment: @EricXue sorry if I come off as dumb, but I'm having trouble understand. I don't know neither the strength nor the distance I want to reduce it to. All I know is Intiital strength and distance

Comment: Hey :). I'll add a simple answer in a moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to scale the light intensity according to the *inverse square law*. <sup>[[Calculator]](https://byjus.com/inverse-square-law-calculator/)</sup>

- When dividing scene size by 6, divide light power by 36.
- When dividing scene size by 10, divide light power by 100

---

**Important note:**
*Point* and *Spot lights* don't change their *Size* when scaled with the scene. You need to change their Size manually in the Lights panel. Area lights scale properly with the rest of the scene.

---

Example:
Scene scale divided by 6. Point light Size also divided by 6. Point light power divided by 36.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, but would I have the need to change the distance of the lamp to the mesh? Since the mesh and scene have gotten smaller, they are farther away from the lamp, even if the lamp is scaled down right? So I would need to move the light?      Or would the changing of the lamp size and strength negate the need to move lamp closer to mesh?

Comment: Yes, you need to change the lamp distance. Just select the whole scene and scale it to 1/6. This way your camera and shadows will match perfectly :).

Comment: Whole scene including lights? But if I scale down the light in viewport , and then do the same in the property/material editor thing, would I not have scaled it down twice, causing an issue?

Comment: Hey :). Point and spot lights don't change their *Size* when you're scaling the scene. Only Area lights do. I updated the answer :).

Comment: so if I change size of area light in viewport, it changes in the editor and vice versa?

Comment: The *Scale* of *Area lights* in viewport multiplies their size (in milimeters/inches) that's set in the Light panel. So yes, you can influence your *Area light* both ways. :)

Comment: so by scaling entire scene down by sixth, my lamp size goes down by a sixth. Do I need to then change area lamp size in the editor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108765/discussion-between-jachym-michal-and-hank-ryan).