# Identical (but smaller) scenes render a slightly different image

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, light, shadows

[image]

I am experimenting around and trying to create an "inception" effect. Basically, a cube splits into several smaller ones and breaks apart, while the camera zooms into one of the smaller cubes. The smaller cube then breaks apart, and it repeats. I want to make this a loop, so to do that I need a start and end frame that look exactly the same.

Unfortunately, for some reason, the end frame which shows the larger (yet identical) cube has a slight but noticeably darker shadow (see the gif below). The light is a sun lamp parented to the camera, so the angle and intensity should be exactly the same. Are there any other possible reasons for why this happens? I have attached the file above so it will make more sense.

[image]

Comment: Probably not an answer, but your sun should probably not be parented to anything. [see doc on sun light](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/lights/light_object.html?#sun-light) *the location of a sun light does not affect the rendered result.*

Comment: Hey :). Can't test the scene now, just keep in mind that the Sun lamp light falloff doesn't follow the [Inverse Square Law](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/180814/78972), which can play a role

Comment: @JachymMichal Yes, this was the specific reason I used a Sun Lamp. I figured that because the light source for the sun lamp is deemed as infinitely far away, there will not be any changes in lighting due to scale.